# Boost::regex_iterator constructor fails but make_regex_iterator function succeeds

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

```
std::string line;
```

This throws `std::runtime_error what():  Memory exhausted`:

```
regex_it =  boost::sregex_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re);
```

This works fine:

```
regex_it = boost::make_regex_iterator(line, re);
```

Does anyone know what is causing the difference in performance?  The boost::regex lib is compiled on Linux in default non-recursive mode.

EDIT:
Also tried

regex_it =  boost::cregex_iterator(line.data(), line.data()+line.size(), re);

same problem.

Comment: What type is `line`, and how big is it?

Comment: added std::string declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try working with a `regex_iterator<char const*>` rather than a `regex_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>`. (Also, the way you're calling `make_regex_iterator` is unnecessarily verbose by a large measure.)

Assuming `line` is a `std::string`, try this:

```
regex_it = boost::make_regex_iterator(line.c_str(), re);
```

or this:

```
regex_it = boost::cregex_iterator(line.data(), line.data() + line.size(), re);
```

Comment: +1 _unnecessarily verbose by a large measure_ -- what a nice way to put it

Comment: I guess I was a bit confused on template function use =P, thanks for that.  That essentially solved my issue in a different way since it was the verbosity that was bugging me.  However the cregex approach does not work, still getting the out of memory error.

Comment: I realized I oversimplified the issue which left out the detail which was causing the problem.  The `line.begin()` and `line.end()` was actually `line.substr(0,pos).begin()` and `line.substr(0,pos).end()`.  Since the substring calls make temporary variables, that is copies of the substring, the begin and end iterators don't refer to the same container.  I'm going to award this answer since it was the only one.

Comment: @Marty : It's not considered bad form to answer your own question. :-]